# Putting HtmlWidget elements in a paragraph

Tags: html, flutter, dart

May I know how to put the elements I get from `HtmlWidget(allwordlist![0].ivakavakayagataki.toString()), HtmlWidget(allwordlist![0].ivakavakayagataki.toString()),`  in a paragraph?

I am making a dictionary application and the above HTML render code works but problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to put these two in a paragraph as in side by side like a sentence.

May I get some help un knowing how to do this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using this package ? 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I made it work.

So I first made this function and not that `<p>` tags so the problem thats was making my HtmlWidget statement not inline and having line breaks was because of the `p` tag so I first took it out.

```
Widget mergehtml(String html1, String html2,){   
    html1 = html1.replaceAll("<p>", "").replaceAll("</p>", "");
    html2 = html2.replaceAll("<p>", "").replaceAll("</p>", "");

    String mergedHtml = "<p style='font-size:18px;'>" + html1 + " " + "[" + html2 + "], " + "</p>" ;
    return HtmlWidget(mergedHtml);
  }
```

and then I called it and put my two variables there.

```
mergehtml("${allwordlist![0].tina}","${allwordlist![0].itavi}",)
```

it then started working inline.

Thanks :)